# how can i create an MacOsx executable file from script

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, ubuntu

Currently I have an executable file in ".command" format. I need to be able to run it on the MacOsx terminal, but when I run it I get the following error:

```
spawn: command not found
couldn't read file "@'s password:": no such file or directory
line 7: send: command not found
couldn't read file "#": no such file or directory
```

The file ".command" works correctly when I execute it, however it closes the shh session with the message:
"[Process completed]"

the code of .command file:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set login "root"
set addr "hostname"
set pw "mypassword"
spawn ssh $login@$addr
expect "$login@$addr's password:"
send "$pw\r"
expect "#"
```

Comment: You need to use `expect send`, or put your commands in curly brackets...

Comment: The errors you're getting suggest that it is `bash` that's executing your script, not `expect`.